# Why calculate fourier series component for k=0?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

we can express a fourier series in the form $$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{L} \sum_{k} e^{kix}\tilde{f_k}$$ where $L$ is the length of the interval of the fourier series and $k = \dfrac{2\pi n}{L}$ is the fourier-mode and $\tilde{f_k}$ the fourier component.

We resolve the fourier component with $$\tilde{f_k} = \int_Ie^{-inx}f(x)dx$$

Usually we do this for

- $k = 0$
- $k \neq 0$

**1. Why do we consider these two different cases?**

**2. Are there other situations where we might consider more special cases?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times $k=0$ is problematic. Imagine the function $f(x)=1$ the integral would become
$$\int e^{-inx}f(x)\mathrm{dx}=\int e^{-inx}\cdot 1\mathrm{dx}=\frac{e^{-inx}}{-in}+c$$

Obviously $n\neq 0$ must be given so that we can integrate the exponential. Hence, me must look at $n=0$ separately.

I dont tinkt to remember a case where i had to look at other cases, but I think it is possible. I am absolutely sure that you have to investigate different cases if you funcion $f(x)$ is strange (e.g. absolute value of something, etc.).

Comment: With your given example $n = 0$ would be a problem as we would have 0 in the denominator?

Comment: Yes exactly :).